# SSRS datepart expression, Error

Tags: reporting-services

I didnt know whats wrong with this expression.This expression always return #error.how to solve this?

```
=MonthName(datepart("M",format(Fields!date.Value,"yyyy-MM-dd"))) + " " + datepart("yyyy",format(Fields!date.Value,"yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

expression works fine with just`=MonthName(datepart("M",format(Fields!date.Value,"yyyy-MM-dd")))`, when added `+ " " + datepart("yyyy",format(Fields!date.Value,"yyyy-MM-dd"))` become error.curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `&` instead of `+` to concatenate strings in SSRS expressions - [Operators in Expressions (Report Builder and SSRS)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255271.aspx)

```
=MonthName(datepart("M",format(Fields!date.Value,"yyyy-MM-dd"))) & " " & datepart("yyyy",format(Fields!date.Value,"yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ===>

```
=MonthName(datepart("m",format(Fields!date.Value,"yyyy-MM-dd"))) + " " + datepart("y",format(Fields!date.Value,"yyyy-MM-dd"))
```